# delphi TStringGrid and right mouse button

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, firemonkey, right-click, tstringgrid

I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin to make a Multi-Device application. I have a `TStringGrid` in order to list some data from a query.

I also have a popup menu (edit, delete, ...), but in order to edit/delete an item I have to click on a cell using the left mouse button.

Is it possible to "select a row" using only the right button before showing the popup menu?

I tried:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbRight then
    StringGrid1.Perform(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MakeLParam(Word(X), Word(Y)));
end;
```

But it displays an error on `mbRight` and on `Perform()`.

Comment: I see that you also added "multidevice application". Please always add a `firemonkey` tag for FMX applications.

Comment: How did you add the `OnMouseDown` event? FMX `TStringGrid` doesn't expose such event.

Comment: [One way](https://pastebin.com/BbTG6pAB).

Comment: Yeah @Victoria Still not `OnMouseDown`:) I was teasing OP on their code which obviously was just copied from the other Q/A. But please enter an answer based on the pastebin

Comment: on formCreate event i wrote 
StringGrid1.OnMouseDown:=StringGrid1MouseDown;

Comment: @Tom it's a public event

Comment: Holy smoke! So it is @David. All the way from TControl. Every day one learns something new is a good day.

Comment: Rube, I made a change to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
procedure TForm39.StringGrid1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: single);
var
  pf: TPointF;
begin
  if Button = TMouseButton.mbRight then
  begin
    with Sender as TStringGrid do
      SelectRow(RowByPoint(X, Y));
  // Do not use the grids PopupMenu property, it seems it
  // prevents this event handler comletely.
  // Instead, activate the menu manually here.
    pf := ClientToScreen(TPointF.Create(X, Y));
    PopupMenu1.Popup(pf.X, pf.Y);
  end;
end;
```

FireMonkey is compiled with [Scoped Enumerations](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Scoped_Enumerations) enabled, so the problem with the `mbRight` button is solved by prefixing the value with its enum type (`TMouseButton.mbRight`).

Comment: WOW! it works!
I modify  PopupMenu1.Popup(pf.X, pf.Y); to  PopupMenu1.Popup(pf.X, pf.Y+70); in order to have popupmenu near mouse cursor!
Thankyou very much @tom

Comment: Thanks @Rube, glad I could help.